# Module parse failed, unexpected token with Webpack Phoenix React Semantic UI Theming

Tags: reactjs, webpack, phoenix-framework, semantic-ui, webpack-4

I am new to react/redux/webpack using Phoenix Framework and am trying to setup a new project from scratch and I encountered Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

I have tried answers to similar questions but havent been able to solve it.

Here is the error:

Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| /* Global */

> & { @import "semantic-ui-less/definitions/globals/reset"; }
>   | & { @import "semantic-ui-less/definitions/globals/site"; }
>   |

webpack config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({ cache: true, parallel: true, sourceMap: false }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  },
  entry: {
    './js/app.js': ['./js/app.tsx']//.concat(glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js'))
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx?|tsx?)$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      // this rule handles images
      {
        test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.ico$|\.png$|\.svg$/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]?[hash]'
      },
      // the following 3 rules handle font extraction
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.otf(\?.*)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=/fonts/[name].  [ext]&mimetype=application/font-otf'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '../css/app.css' }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }])
  ],
  resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  }
});
```

app.tsx

```
import 'semantic-ui-less/semantic.less'

import "phoenix_html"
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

// Import local files
//
// Local files can be imported directly using relative paths, for example:
// import socket from "./socket"
import Root from './Root'

// This code starts up the React app when it runs in a browser. It sets up the routing
// configuration and injects the app into a DOM element.
ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('react-app'))
```